# Can PCB (process control block) be bigger than process image?

Tags: operating-system

My question refers to any OS (preferably Windows and Linux). Is there a case when process image is smaller than PCB?

Comment: I think this question is off-topic and should be posted here instead: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Process Control Block in any operating system I am aware of. The Process Control Block is the invention of some horrible text books. For most people dealing with operating system PCB means Process Context Block. That is the block where a process's (or thread's) registered are stored. The PCB structure is defined by the underlying hardware.

Operating systems must maintain other data about the state of the process (e.g., for paging, scheduling, privileges) That is typically stored in multiple structures that are linked together. Combined, these structures and the Process Context Block(s) are the mythical Process Control Block that idiotic textbooks describe.

These kernel blocks could conceivably be larger than the user mode image of the process.